# Google map is wrong displayed until resizing webpage with GWT Google Map API3

Tags: java, google-maps, gwt, google-maps-api-3

My Application (a single Web page application) use GWT-Maps-V3-Api-3.8.1 to create Google Map. The application has many View. There are two view (view A and View B) using  GWT-Maps-V3-Api-3.8.1. At the first time go to webpage, if I open view A before view B, the map in view A is OK and when i navigate to view B the map in view B show incorrect as bellow
[image]

Similarly, if the fistime go to web page, I open View B before view A. The map in View B Ok but the map in vew A has error as above.
 Here is the code i use to create the map

```
public class UiGoogleMap implements IsWidget,ClickMapHandler {

private MapWidget mapWidget=null;

private EventBus eventBus = null;

private List<UiMarker> selectedMarkers = new ArrayList<UiMarker>();

/**
 * ....
 * Some feild here
 * ....
 */


/**
 * Construct the Google map V3 without using {@link EventBus},
 * asynchronously loads the Maps API.
 */
public UiGoogleMap() {
    this(null);
}

public UiGoogleMap(EventBus bus) {
    this(bus, "");
}


public UiGoogleMap(EventBus bus, String mapApiKey) {
    super();
mapWidget=new MapWidget(MapOptions.newInstance());
    this.eventBus = bus;
    initMap();

    mapController = new MapController(mapWidget);
}
private void initMap() {
    mapWidget.setZoom(zoomLevel);
    mapWidget.addClickHandler(this);

    mapWidget.addIdleHandler(new IdleMapHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onEvent(IdleMapEvent event) {
            mapWidget.setSize("100%", "100%");
        }
    });
}
```

i checked the div of mapWidget in correct situation is

```
<div class="gwt-map-MapWidget-div"><div style="overflow: hidden;"></div></div>
```

and the div of mapWidget in incorrect situation is

```
<div class="gwt-map-MapWidget-div" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223);"><div class="gm-style" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0; cursor: url(http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/openhand_8_8.cur) 8 8, default;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 1; width: 100%; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);"><div style="-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 100; width: 100%;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 0;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 1;"></div></div></div><div style="-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 101; width: 100%;"></div><div style="-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 102; width: 100%;"></div><div style="-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 103; width: 100%;"></div><div style="position: absolute; z-index: 0;"><div style="overflow: hidden;"></div></div></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 2; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 3; width: 100%; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);"><div style="-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 104; width: 100%;"></div><div style="-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 105; width: 100%;"></div><div style="-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 106; width: 100%;"></div><div style="-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 107; width: 100%;"></div></div></div></div></div>
```

when i change size of window browser (minimize,etc...) the error map change size and give the correct map
[image]

I think maybethe problem is

> mapWidget=new MapWidget(MapOptions.newInstance());

this code create different code div as above and cause the problem.
Thank for any help.

FIXED: I have fixed above error by add the handler

```
mapWidget.addIdleHandler(new IdleMapHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onEvent(IdleMapEvent event) {
             MapHandlerRegistration.trigger(mapWidget, MapEventType.RESIZE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is the Java API and therefore should not be tagged with the javascript api v3 tag. With the js API you should call the map resize event when switching from view A to B. There might be a similar thing in Java.

Comment: Because GWT-Maps-V3-Api base on js Google API v3, so I need help from both people who work with js and java to find the solution and the corresponding API in java.  Unfortunately, I had tried find the triggerResize in 3.8.1 before asked this question and have no solution. thank for your help

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `triggerResize` method: http://branflake2267.github.io/GWT-Maps-V3-Api/javadoc/3.9.0-build-17/

Maybe something like: `mapWidget.getMap().triggerResize();`

Comment: in GWT-Maps-V3-Api-3.8.1 there are no mapWidget.getMap().triggerResize();  . There are many different 3.8.1 and 3.9. May be I would try upgare 3.8.1 to 3.9. Thank you very much.

Comment: Well yes maybe an upgrade would be a good idea. I didn't realize you were on 3.8.1.

Comment: I have fixed the problem for 3.8.1. I put my answer above.